# Html.DropDownListFor with pre- selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

My application: MVC, C#, Razor

I have a `Dictionary` table. It has two foreign keys: `LanguageFrom` and `LanguageTo`.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Dictionary dictionary = db.Dictionary.Single(d => d.DictionaryId == id);
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.LanguageFrom = new SelectList(db.Language, "LanguageId", "Name", db.Language.First(a => a.LanguageId == dictionary.LanguageFrom));
        ViewBag.LanguageTo = new SelectList(db.Language, "LanguageId", "Name", db.Language.First(a => a.LanguageId == dictionary.LanguageTo));
        return View(dictionary);
    }
```

Now I need to display two drop down lists with selected languages pre- selected:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LanguageFrom, (ViewBag.LanguageFrom as SelectList))
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LanguageTo, ViewBag.LanguageTo as SelectList)
```

The problem is that my drop down lists both display first items on the list not the ones being currently selected.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property name of your model should not match the ViewBag (ViewData) key. Make the following changes to your code:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)    
{
    Dictionary dictionary = db.Dictionary.Single(d => d.DictionaryId == id);
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // change the ViewBag key for the collection of languages to something else
    // as it matches the LanguageFrom & LanguageTo properties of the Dictionary object
    ViewBag.Languages = new SelectList(db.Language, "LanguageId", "Name");
    return View(dictionary);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LanguageFrom, ViewBag.Languages as SelectList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LanguageTo, ViewBag.Languages as SelectList)
```

The framework will pick up the values from the `LanguageFrom` and  `LanguageTo` properties by itself.

Comment: It works. What logic is behind this mechanism? Why does framework pick up the values itself?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is an open source, so if you are interested in the framework you can check the source code any time.